# How do I use Machine Learning to analyze process statistics of automated test results?

Tags: python, classification

(I am newbieeee in machine learning)

At the end of every automated test (Python), I collect a lot of information from our product. The information includes CPU, Memory Usage, Disk Activity, Postfix Queue statistics, and various other stats.

I want to come up with a script/tool(Python) that leverages machine learning and automatically analyze the results for me, instead of me looking at the results manually every day. I want to train the tool on what acceptable levels are for various components like CPU, Memory, depending on product's specifications, and various inputs.

From what I read online, I think I need to implement supervised classification in my tool, build a model, train it for a few days. But what I don’t know is where to start. When I looked at [Supervised learning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html), I see a bunch of stuff and don’t really know what is really relevant to me. I appreciate if I can get some suggestions on what I need to focus on and how to implement this.

All the data can be in memory before my original script completes, or I can get the data from a database to which my original script writes to.

Comment: Based on all these features like Memory usage, Disk Activity, etc what is the target variable that you analyze everyday based on these stats?

Comment: @Nain, All these are the target variables. If the CPU utilization is higher than what the model is trained for, then it should be flagged. Similarly, if the postfix hold queue size is higher, that's a flag. I want to define a scenario (incoming email rate n per/sec, email size S kb, etc) and for each scenario, I want to train the model. The CPU could be higher for one scenario but still it could be expected. Did I answer your question?

Comment: a) What output do you want? Two-class classification: *'Normal'/'Excessive'*, or n-class: *'Low'/'Medium'/'High'/'Excessive'/...*? b) Have you labeled the examples? c) Do you want to individually classify each variable (CPU, Memory, Disk), or just classify the entire record?

Answer (score 4):

> I want to come up with a script/tool(Python) that **leverages machine learning** and automatically analyze the results for me, instead of me looking at the results manually every day.

This is the wrong approach. Choose your tools to solve tasks, not because they sound cool. Imagine a craftsman saying "I want to use a hammer". (However, machine learning might still suit to this task.)

> From what I read online, I think I need to [...] train it for a few days.

Depends on how much data, how much features, how much computing power and which algorithm you use. In many cases you can train a model within seconds on a normal computer.

### The real question

The problem: You have some characteristics (features) like CPU usage, memory usage, ... for every automated test. For some instances (meaning a test and the associated features) you have the binary information "normal", "abnormal". Now, when you get the characteristics of a new test, you want to automatically decide if it was normal or abnormal.

This is a binary classification problem. If you have the label ("normal", "abnormal") for all instances, you can apply supervised learning methods. If you have the label only for some instances, it is semi-supervised learning. If you don't have any labels it is unsupervised.

### The Answer

I assume you are in a supervised learning case. Then, I would suggest to use a [decision tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) (see [`sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) - sklearn is pretty easy to use and has many standard algorithms implemented) for this decision making. It basically automatically generates many nested if/else statements to get to the decision. Hence it is interpretable and you could manually adjust or improve it.